# NodeJS object.keys error

Tags: javascript, node.js

My nodeJS script needs to make a put/post action to provide an xml file as payload.

However it keeps on failing here saying :

```
     Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
            ^
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at Object.exports.getBodyString
```

printing data to stdout gives me the whole xml file in text.
The type of data is string.

```
    exports.getBodyString = function(data) {  var body = '';

 if(data && !this.isEmpty(data)){
     Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      var val = data[key];
      if (exports.isArray(val)) {
       for (var i=0; i<val.length; i++) {
        body += key + '[]=' + encodeURIComponent(val[i]) + '&';
       }
      } else {
       body += key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(val) + '&';
      }
     });
     return body;  }  return null; };
```

What I try to recreate is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @config.xml "http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start"
```

**to conclude**
How do I properly parse a while xml file (indents and new lines and everything) to proper JSON? I'm struggling with xml2js. That seems to return [Object], [Object], ... instead of proper values.

Comment: A string isn't an object, and doesn't have keys. What are you trying to achieve by iterating over the keys?

Comment: `string` is not an object (a non-object), so `Object.keys()` will not work on it. You likely need to convert the XML to an object first.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that string, but it used to work before but I can't find what I changed (probably the input)..
I'm using this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-oozie

Comment: Have you looked at [node.js querystring](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) or [qs library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/qs) ?

Comment: Since I'm really not good at JS I think it might be easier to change the file input. Right now I just stream the xml file to a string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can still just deliver the xml file and skip the whole function when using

```
headers: {"content-type": "application/xml"}
```

instead of

```
headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
```